# Pylons - catching errors before redirect to document/error for logging

Tags: python, logging, pylons

I want to log 404 and 500 errors in a pylons app before they redirect to my custom error message (/error/document).

My problem is that since Pylons does the redirect, I am unable to determine the page on which the error occurred inside the error controller. So without building a parser for the paster.log I don't know a good way to selectively log just the few relevant pieces of data I want: url, referring page, and stack trace.

Ideally, I would like to access the page the error occurred on, the referring page, as well as the full stack trace and throw that into a couchdb for some quick and easy reports.

Comment: Do you have disabled debug in `development.ini`?

Answer (score 1):

For custom error handling i think you should look at ErrorHandler and StatusCodeRedirect (from pylons.middleware) and maybe make your own class based on them?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original Pylons request and response object from the current request. From there, you can grab the data you need:

```
request = self._py_object.request.environ['pylons.original_request']
response = self._py_object.request.environ['pylons.original_response']
url = request.environ.get("PATH_INFO")
```

I'm not sure how to get the referring page or what stack trace you want, but I'm willing to bet it's in there somewhere.